# How to establish a single socket connection in EJB Message driven bean deployed in weblogic server?

Tags: java, sockets, ejb, weblogic, message-driven-bean

I have a applciation deployed in weblogic server as MDB.This utility will read the messages queued into JMS and send it to a server using socket connection.
To acheive this, how can i establish  a single socket connection at EJB/container level so that the messages can be send to server once the connection is established.

Comment: My interpretation of your question is you want a single instance of the MDB so messages are handled sequentially (instead of concurrently) since there can be only one socket connection to some other server.  If true, [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24977/life_cycle.htm#WLMDB400) might be a good starting point to configure WebLogic.

Comment: Basically the socket connection should be established only once. SO I want to create a logic where i will connect to socket if its not connected or else i will not connect it.
If socket is in connected state then i will send the messages one by one